# Postgresql double transaction?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I got an example of a SQL code with 2 transactions, one after the other. Is that even possible? And if so which one prevails and what would the answer be?

Gonna paste the code >

```
    CREATE TABLE cc ( 
  num integer PRIMARY KEY, 
  salary numeric(6,2) DEFAULT 0 
); 

INSERT INTO cc VALUES (1111, 1000.00); 
INSERT INTO cc VALUES (2222, 2000.00);

Session1 BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED; 
Session1 UPDATE cc SET salary = salary - 100.00 WHERE num = 2222; 
    Session2 BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED; 
    Session2 UPDATE cc SET salary = salary + 100.00 WHERE num = 2222; 
Session1 ROLLBACK; 
    Session2 COMMIT;
```

So, 1st of all, is that possible in PostgreSQL? What is the logic of 2 transactions? And judging by the example, after ROLLBACK 1st and COMMIT 2nd, which is the final salary?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: As a simple guess, is the answer 2100.00? Cause if the 1st is ROLLBACK and you just COMMIT the 2nd then it should just sum. Right?

Comment: Right. The transactions are concurrent, executed on two different connections. Is it possible? Concurrency is one of the fundamental features of any RDBMS.

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention that. Each session is from different connection. But isn't ISOLATION lock the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flow with comments:

```
Session1 BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED; 
Session1 UPDATE cc SET salary = salary - 100.00 WHERE num = 2222; 
-> Session 1 locks row 2222

    Session2 BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED; 
    Session2 UPDATE cc SET salary = salary + 100.00 WHERE num = 2222; 
    -> Session 2 waits for row 2222

Session 1 ROLLBACK; 
-> Session 1 frees row 2222
    -> Session 2 executes UPDATE

    Session 2 COMMIT;
    -> UPDATE 2 is commited
```

`BEGIN TRANSACTION` does not lock anything. `UPDATE` locks row(s) to be modified.

Read about [Transaction Isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html) and [BEGIN.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-begin.html)